# SAX function of TSclust package generate an error

Tags: r, time-series, tsclust

I am using [TSclust](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TSclust/TSclust.pdf) package for SAX (symbolic aggregate aggregation) plots. In accordance to example shown on [page 25](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TSclust/TSclust.pdf), I am using the function

```
SAX.plot(as.ts(df$power), w=30, alpha=4)
```

But, it generates error as:

```
Error in if ((n <- as.integer(n[1L])) > 0) { : argument is of length zero
```

I am not able to debug it. Even I looked into the source code of SAX.plot function but I do not find the relevant error message typed in.

The required R dataobject can be found at [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aon4w42p1ibin4q/mydata.Rdata?dl=0)

R version: 3.2
TSclust version:1.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello apparently it's because you need to normalize your data, check out this example :

```
# Parameters
w <- 30 
alpha <- 4 

# PAA
x <- df$power
paax <- PAA(x, w) 
plot(x, type="l", main="PAA reduction of series x") 
p <- rep(paax,each=length(x)/length(paax)) #just for plotting the PAA
lines(p, col="red")

# SAX
convert.to.SAX.symbol(paax , alpha)
# [1] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
# You need to scale PAA result
convert.to.SAX.symbol(scale(paax) , alpha)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 4 3 3 1 2 2 2 4 4 4 1 1 2 4 3 3 4 4


# SAX plot : with scaling this works
SAX.plot(as.ts(scale(df$power)), w=w, alpha=alpha)
```

That's likely the example you can found in the function help page.

Comment: thanks. One small curious question: How did you find that non-normalized data are causing problems.

Comment: You're welcome! I just checked the steps in `SAX.plot` function and repeat these manually and saw the problem in `convert.to.SAX.symbol` when you don't scale your data.